# update sql en sqlite3

Tags: python, sqllite

si realizo una consulta de esta forma:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('numeros.db')
consulta = conn.cursor()

consulta.execute(""" UPDATE total set suma = 1 
                  WHERE numeros = 1 """)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

donde tengo 10 registros con números y un total, que representa un valor cada vez que los uso
esto funciona, pero ¿cómo puedo reemplazar ese valor del registro por una variable?, algo así:

```
numero = 3
ahora = 2
consulta.execute(""" UPDATE total set suma = ahora 
                      WHERE numeros = numero """)
```

intente poniendo las  variables entre comillas y con ? como si fuese un insert y tampoco funciona

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente amigo, para concatenar variables con una cadena de texto

```
numero = 3
 ahora = 2
consulta.execute(""" UPDATE total set suma ="""+ ahora+ 
                      """WHERE numeros ="""+ numero)
```

Comment: me dio error ya que no se puede concatenar cadenas con enteros, pero por tu respuesta caí en la cuenta que es una simple cadena!! lo solucioné en base a lo que me dijiste así: consulta.execute(f""" UPDATE total set suma = {ahora} 
                 WHERE numeros = {numero}""")